# Estou tentando construir uma API REST com Laravel onde os usuários precisam atualizar sua imagem. Mas, se eu usar o método PUT a imagem não é enviada

Tags: php, laravel, postman

Estou testando com o Postan uma api rest que eu implementei usando Laravel 9, quando eu faço a requisição no Postman utilizando o metodo put atualiza as informações de do tipo numerica e string, poré a imagem não é enviada porque não é possivel enviar arquivos com o metodo put; se eu defino o metodo post da um erro dizendo que a rota não suporta o metodo post. Como eu resolvo isso?

Estas são as rotas.

```
Route::get('/cardapio',[MenusControllers::class, 'index']);
Route::get('/cardapio/{id}',[MenusControllers::class, 'show']);
Route::post('/register',[AuthController::class, 'register']);


Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth:sanctum']], function(){
    Route::post('/cardapio',[MenusControllers::class, 'store']);
    Route::put('/cardapio/update/{id}',[MenusControllers::class, 'update']);
    Route::delete('/cardapio/{id}',[MenusControllers::class, 'destroy']);

});
```

Este é o controller relacionado a rota

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $menu = Menu::findOrFail($id);

        /**/if($request->hasFile('image') && $request->file('image')->isValid()){
            $requestImage = $request->image;
            $name = uniqid();
            $extension = $requestImage->extension();
            $imageName = "{$name}.{$extension}";
            $requestImage->move(public_path('img/public', $imageName));
            $menu->image = $imageName;
        }else{
            return response('Não está definido');
        }

        $menu->save();

        $menu->update($request->all());

        return response([200]);
```

Como posso resolver este problema?

Answer (score -2):

Oi! Tudo bem?
Vou colocar aqui um trecho de código para você ver como eu faço.

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    //...
    $marca = $this->marca->find($id); //$marca é minha Model (Injeção de dependência)

    if ($marca === null) {
        return response()->json(["erro"=>"Marca não existe. ID inválido!"],404);
    }

    $dados = $request->all();

    if ($request->file('imagem')) {
        $image = $request->file('imagem');
        $imagem_urn = $image->store('imagens'); //Salva a imagem em disco
        $dados["imagem"] = $imagem_urn; //Para guardar o path da imagem

        Storage::disk('local')->delete($marca->imagem); //Faço isso para deletar a imagem antiga
    }

    $marca->update($dados);
    return response()->json($marca,200);
    //...
}
```

Espero que te ajude.

[]s